# Paradox between Heisenberg and ground state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, atoms, ground-state

According to Heisenberg principle if the electron is near the nuclei it is more likely to have a greater momentum $p$. So the energy must be greater. But the electron loses energy and has in fact lower value in the ground state. What is wrong here?

Comment: An electron in a hydrogen atom does in fact have more momentum in the ground state than in its excited states, even though the total kinetic plus potential energy is more negative. A search term is "virial theorem."

Comment: If it is as you say then uncertainty of p near nuclei should be smaller. But HUP states opposite.

Comment: You have it backwards. A confined particle has small $∆x$, and so must have large $∆p$.

Answer (score 2):

> According to Heisenberg principle if the electron is near the nuclei
> it is more likely to have a greater momentum $p$.
> So the energy must be greater.

You need to distinguish between *kinetic* energy and *total* energy.
You are right, that a small uncertainty of position $\Delta x$
enforces a large uncertainty of momentum $$\Delta p \approx \frac{h}{\Delta x}.$$
From this you can conclude that the kinetic energy is large:
$$E_\text{kin}=\frac{p^2}{2m} \approx \frac{h^2}{2m(\Delta x)^2}. \tag{1}$$

> But the electron loses energy and has in fact lower value in the ground state.
> What is wrong here?

You forgot that total energy consists not only of kinetic energy (estimated above),
but also of potential energy. This potential energy is actually negative
and larger than the kinetic energy.
For example: In the hydrogen atom, from the [virial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_theorem) you know
$$E_\text{pot}=-2E_\text{kin} \tag{2}$$

So from (1) and (2) you get the total energy
$$E_\text{tot}=E_\text{kin}+E_\text{pot}
=-E_\text{kin}
\approx -\frac{p^2}{2m} \approx -\frac{h^2}{2m(\Delta x)^2}$$
which is a large *negative* quantity.

So there is no paradox anymore.
When the atom transitions from an excited state
(larger $\Delta x$) to the ground state (smaller $\Delta x$),
then the total energy $E_\text{total}$ decreases
(becomes more negative), as it should be.

Comment: Thanks. That clears the issue.  But that leaves the feeling that potential energy is some mathematical construct. Can PE be somehow explained by the field or by virtual particles.

Comment: @Mercury Well, sure. You may call
"[electric potential energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential_energy)"
a mathematical construct. But eventually all physical therories are mathematical constructs, justified by their predictive power.
On a deeper level eletromagnetic interaction can be understood as the exchange of
[virtual photons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_photon),
exchangend between charged particles.
But that is another story (called "quantum electrodynamics").

Answer (score -1):

There's no paradox because you have misinterpreted the uncertainty principle.

The uncertainty principle deals with the spread of possible values (the deltas) for measurements of two related quantities (related in the mathematical sense of the formalism of quantum theory).  It does **not** relate the actual values of the quantities.

Comment: This isn't really correct. For example, if the expectation value of the vector momentum is zero, $\left< p \right>=0$, the uncertainty in the momentum $\sigma_p^2=\left<p^2\right>-\left<p\right>^2$ is proportional to the mean kinetic energy.